# ajax call back not working with knockout.js

Tags: ajax

I am having problems with this save function.
the line with comment `//←this does not` is not working, however the line with comment `//←this one works` is working. Is there anything wrong with calling it in the ajax callback? How can I get it to work?

```
save= function(){
    var self=this;
    function f(index, row){
    jsRow=ko.toJS(row)
        if (jsRow.isChanged) {
            var value= jsRow.value;
            self.commitRowToUndo(row); //←this one works
            $.ajax({
                url: "db/"+value._id, 
                type: "put",
                data: JSON.stringify(value),
                success:  function(responce_json) {
                    self.commitRowToUndo(row); //←this does not
                    …
                    var row= something;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    $.each(self.table.rows(), f);
}
```

---

`save` is bound to a button.

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools console?

Answer (score 2):

I found it: it was because I declared row latter, row became undefined. I did not realise that defining a variable had retro-active scope. (I will define variable at top of function/scope in Javascript from now on).